# android gridview stop selecting clicking effect when change layout

Tags: android

Below is my gridview layout which works fine and clicks. But when I change my layout it's not clicking any more. Tell me why I just change xml not code. Tell me what is wrong in my xml? Why gridView stopped clicking? is it because of layout weight?

I'm changing from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
        android:text="Order Now"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15pt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry please try to be more specific with wour question and describe what you mean by clicking and show your Java code

Comment: when using first xml code wheni click any image is move to desire action go selected image but when i used second xml code it s not selecting and perform action

Comment: please checkmy layout weights? its properly assign????

Comment: No they aren't. Please use the layout at my answer and try again. If your problem occurs again post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have some spaces in your layout maybe your click events did not trigger becasue of this. Just use below layout and check if your problem is solved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#58FA58"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#DF013A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2EFEF7" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="dummy"/>

</LinearLayout>
```