# How can I use layout_weight to make a two-column layout above a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make this layout:

[image: layout]

This is my xml code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Push the button"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exampleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The button"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: help me please how i chnage layout like image???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made me laugh with your drawing thanks:) BTW you can do that with a textView and a button like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="dummy text 1 \n dummy text 2"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or something more complex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dummyImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#58FA58"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myDummyTextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#DF013A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myDummyTextView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2EFEF7" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="dummy"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or more efficient with relativeLayout. That will be another issue, [read more about it](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html). But I'd prefer first one if it is enough for you.

Comment: no i want same like my image    imageview with two textview on right and button on bottom

Comment: See my updated answer. That'll be ok for you. But I suggest you to use a relative layout after understanding layouts on android.

Comment: is lok fine but there is 1 problem tell me about that

Comment: Edited. I hope you liked it now.

Comment: i see a problem im confuse about that

Comment: is show same peoblem which i face at this question i pose ealier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684076/android-gridview-stop-selecting-clickicng-effect-when-change-layout  see this

Comment: What is the problem in this layout? I'm looking to your other problem but if this one is solved mark it as an answer.

Comment: im using this layout in gridview porblem is when i remove button in thislayoout its lod perfectly in gridview also clickbale but when i add button in this layout is not clickable tel me why????

Comment: this is not relevant to your question. ask another one.